# What is the meaning of the shaded area in the reinforcement learning literature graphs?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, papers

In most of the reinforcement learning literature, I see that there is a shaded area in the graphs. I couldn't understand what it exactly represents?

For example, from the A3C paper:

[image]

Or another example from the PPO paper:

[image]

Is it for multiple runs or it's for something else? How I can reproduce such graphs (which library and what type of data from my training episode do I need)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They train the agent multiple times, then plot the mean +- standard deviation of the agent performance (the shaded region is representing the standard deviation).